# Window resize example from Pygame wiki not working

Tags: python, events, resize, pygame, window-resize

I took [this tutorial from pygame.org](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/WindowResizing?parent=CookBook) which should show how to resize the window properly (image has to be supplied to it, you can use for instance [my gravatar](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/00c5384c01d44ec1bbc4c035638c3042?s=164&d=identicon&r=PG)). The image should resize to the window, but this doesn't happen with me. Only one `VideoResize` event is created as soon as I resize the window even so slightly:

```
<Event(16-VideoResize {'h': 500, 'w': 501, 'size': (501, 500)})>
```

No other `VideoResize` events are created (other things like mouse movement or keypresses work). So is the tutorial wrong? Is my computer wrong? **What is the proper way of doing it?**

I'm running: Python 2.7.5, Pygame 1.9.1, Fedora 20, MATE 1.8.1, Toshiba Satellite.

Here's the code (slightly modified to print the event, but neither the original nor this one work):

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500), RESIZABLE)
pic = pygame.image.load("example.png")
screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pic, (500,500)), (0,0))
pygame.display.flip()
done = False

while not done:
    pygame.event.pump()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
            print event # show all VIDEORESIZE events
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'], RESIZABLE) # A
            screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pic, event.dict['size']), (0,0))
            pygame.display.flip()

pygame.display.quit()
```

If I comment the line `# A`, then I get plenty of events, but this is the line which resizes the window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70441/discussion-between-yo-and-malik-brahimi).

Answer (score 0):

Well I ran the tutorial example with only one change which is I used a pic of a cat called cat.png and it worked fine. The resize is working you just grab a corner and it allows me to adjust it freely with dragging. The picture fills the window whatever size I make it. Have you done other scripts with pygame successfully?

Comment: I also just checked the code you provided only changed the pic used and modified the line print event to print (event) but thats for Python 3.2 which is what I use. The window popped up and shows the picture and allows me to resize it freely like the other. It shows the events in the console looks like this.

Comment: <Event(16-VideoResize {'h': 619, 'w': 909, 'size': (909, 619)})>
<Event(16-VideoResize {'h': 638, 'w': 697, 'size': (697, 638)})>
<Event(16-VideoResize {'h': 603, 'w': 812, 'size': (812, 603)})>
<Event(16-VideoResize {'h': 671, 'w': 735, 'size': (735, 671)})>
<Event(16-VideoResize {'h': 616, 'w': 790, 'size': (790, 616)})>
<Event(16-VideoResize {'h': 585, 'w': 777, 'size': (777, 585)})>
<Event(16-VideoResize {'h': 625, 'w': 639, 'size': (639, 625)})>

Comment: Well, you' re not the first person to report that it works for them, but still, I don't understand why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Not sure where you got pygame from but this looked promising. http://pkgs.org/fedora-20/fedora-x86_64/pygame-1.9.1-14.fc20.x86_64.rpm.html I hope it helps I know all to well how frustrating it can be when certain aspects of a program fail to work.

Comment: This sounds like the same problem your having. https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issue/201/videoresize-only-issued-once-further

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it. It seems to be a problem of only a very limited number of people. Thanks for finding it. I found a stupid workaround that does the job just now, but it's really bad.

Comment: Well this appears to be a SDL issue that has been going on for a while not sure when It will be fixed I'm sorry I was unable to getting it working for you.  https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issue/129/videoresize-not-generated-when-returning

Comment: Good to hear you may wish to post the work around so that if someone else has the problem they can fix it somewhat.

Comment: Well, I tracked that for me this happens only with dragging the LB corner. Dragging on the sides works ok. So that's the workaround.